What is Express's view setting?
// register a new view constructor
app.set('view', GithubView);

In the expressjs example of view constructor encoutered this snippet. Couldn't find any documentation about the view setting of express.

There is a default View class in Express that controls how templates are located, loaded, and rendered. By change the view setting through app.set('view', CustomeViewClass), you can instruct Express to use your custom View class, therefore override how Express locates and retrieves templates.
Snippet of function render from the application.js file of Express shows how the View class get loaded accroding to the view setting.
if (!view) {
    var View = this.get('view');

    view = new View(name, {
      defaultEngine: this.get('view engine'),
      root: this.get('views'),
      engines: engines
    });

    if (!view.path) {
      var dirs = Array.isArray(view.root) && view.root.length > 1
        ? 'directories "' + view.root.slice(0, -1).join('", "') + '" or "' + view.root[view.root.length - 1] + '"'
        : 'directory "' + view.root + '"'
      var err = new Error('Failed to lookup view "' + name + '" in views ' + dirs);
      err.view = view;
      return done(err);
    }

    // prime the cache
    if (renderOptions.cache) {
      cache[name] = view;
    }
  }

